# Dark screen after implementing JB4ASDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios

I'm following the docs in the following link in order to implement the iOS SDk. I'm using the libJB4ASDK-4.0.0.a version.

http://exacttarget.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk.html

I don't have credentials yet but the demo app provided doesn't have and it continue to loads anyways, in my case I'm getting a dark screen and that's it.

The App runs fine if I remove the method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

Note: maybe because the docs are for version 3.5.0 and I'm the most recent ones (4.0.0)?

tkx

Answer (score 0):

I was going to delete this question however reading the docs I figured out my issue.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

> Tells the delegate when the app has finished launching.
>   Although not formally deprecated, you should not use this method in
>   your apps. Use the `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and
>   `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` methods instead.

So, basically if you are using `applicationDidFinishLaunching` consider using the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (it is used in the SDK implementation docs)

Tkx